# How set default value of a session variable in yii?

Tags: yii

I need to keep in session some details about the user.

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$user->id;           
        $this->setState('username', $user->username);           
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

In the example I save the username -  `$this->setState('username', $user->username);`
In the main page when I call is the first time `$username=Yii::app()->user->username;` I got Property "CWebUser.username" is not defined. Is there a way to set a deafult value to username and other sessian variables. I need to know the right way to do so. Will it be right to add just `$this->setState('username', "");`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> ```
> Yii::app()->user->getState('username', $default_val);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with

```
$this->setState('username', "");
```

but you don't have reason to do it, because your *else* clause is executed only when the user with the provided *username* is founded.
If you want to validate that user is guest, use:

```
Yii::app()->user->isGuest
```